# Port mapping not added to ECS container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I'm attempting to run a web server on an ECS cluster, using the 'amazon/amazon-ecs-sample' container.

My cluster is backed by an ASG-based capacity provider.

I've attempted to achieve this, by using the `host` network mode on my task, and adding a TCP port mapping from host port 80 to container port 80 on the container like so:

```
    const taskDefinition = new ecs.Ec2TaskDefinition(
      this, 
      'TaskDef',
      {
        networkMode: ecs.NetworkMode.HOST,
      }
    );

    taskDefinition.addContainer('web', {
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('amazon/amazon-ecs-sample'),
      memoryReservationMiB: 256,
      portMappings: [{
        containerPort: 80,
        hostPort: 80,
        protocol: ecs.Protocol.TCP
      }]
    });
```

However, when I ssh into my host, and run `sudo docker ps`, it does not appear that this port mapping exists:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                  PORTS     NAMES
3fd0869a3617   amazon/amazon-ecs-sample         "/usr/sbin/apache2 -…"   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes                      ecs-SdInfraStackTaskDef029720EC-4-web-e695b2eaf8acf8c32500
36174f23403b   amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest   "/agent"                 18 hours ago    Up 18 hours (healthy)             ecs-agent
```

What is missing and how can I achieve this?